# Twilio 'Header' import issue

Tags: twilio, twilio-node

When i installed latest twilio's version which is "twilio": "^4.7.2", and building the project (`npm run build`) the following error occurs,

```
node_modules/twilio/lib/base/BaseTwilio.d.ts:22:19 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Headers'.

22         headers?: Headers;
                     ~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in node_modules/twilio/lib/base/BaseTwilio.d.ts:22
```

My node version : v16.18.1

Npm version : v8.19.2

Comment: Can you add more details on your machine or maybe try it on another system? I just tested it on my machine with v16.18.0 (npm v8.19.2) and I could install "^4.7.2"

Comment: npm version :
8.19.2

Comment: node version : 16.18.1

Comment: @IObert I can also able to install but while building the project using `npm run build` i am getting the above error

Comment: Can you please add more information about the kind of project you try to build? Please add instructions how to reproduce this issue too.

Comment: Its a Node service project.

Comment: To reproduce this issue : Install twilio's latest version and try to call any one of its API

Comment: Please provide full instructions with a code snippet in your original question.

Comment: I've got the same issue. The project can't be built. This is what I get `node_modules/twilio/lib/base/BaseTwilio.d.ts(22,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Headers'.`

Comment: @IObert well you don't need any snippets. I guess the problem is in some typescript settings. I get the same error, but all I did is just install twilio of the same version

Comment: I am seeing this issue as well in a node express environment. Hacking with `skipLibCheck` is not the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue once I installed the `twilio` npm package of the exact same version `^4.7.2`. I'm assuming it's some typescript compilation issue. And there is a trick that you can use to make it work.

Add this in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true,
    }
}
```

This will solve your issue, but don't consider it as a fix. It's rather workaround.
P.S. This will also speed up your overall typescript compilation process.